# Strange jdbcReam Exception occurs on Tomcat

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, jdbcrealm

I have a simple java one-servlet web-application restricted with BASIC authentication on my localhost. It works fine if I use default UserDatabaseRealm.

I try to use jdbcReaml - projectName/META-INF/context.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/projectName">
      <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
              driverName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/realm"
              connectionName="****" connectionPassword="****"
              userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
              userRoleTable="roles" roleNameCol="user_role" />
 </Context>
```

My database is filled with users and their passwords, also I created roles for users.
Authentication woks fine, but each time client fills in his auth data Exception occurs:

```
02-Jul-2014 14:42:37.406 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getPassword Exception performing authentication
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement has been closed.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2631)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setString(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1373)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.credentials(JDBCRealm.java:484)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.getPassword(JDBCRealm.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:387)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:334)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:578)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1033)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I spend a lot of time tryng to solve this problem.

As far as I know I suppose that problem appears during PostgresQL connection. My code does nothing with database connection.
How can I solve this problem?

I don't want to use DataSourceRealm with connection pool, I just want to solve my problem and move on with tomcat.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, when going from Tomcat-6 with Java-6 to Tomcat-8 with Java-7. What are your Tomact/java versions?

Comment: It seems that Tomcat-8 is to blame? I don't have the problem with Tomcat-7 (and everything else exactly the same)

Comment: Problem appears on Tomcat 8 and Java 7. Still didn't solve this problem. I used DataSourceRealm instead (it uses pooling). 
It's interesting to learn the aim of JdbcRealm using.

Answer (score 3):

This problem resulted from a refactoring done in march 2014. It was fixed recently and should be in tomcat 8.0.19.

Comment: Can you please link to the GitHub/JIRA issue on this? Thank you

Comment: It didn't get a Bugzilla issue, but the fix can be found [in rev 1657683](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc8.0.x/trunk@1657683) and is represented in the change notes as *"Fix exception while authentication in JDBCRealm."* for Apache Tomcat 8.0.19 and released with version 8.0.20.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a problem with one end of the connection closing due to a timeout. This could be the postgres server closing the connection or tomcat closing the connection. I recommend configuring the realm to use a jndi datasource that is configured in tomcat as well this will allow you to configure the timeout for the connection. You might have to play with the configuration for the datasource.

Datasource configuration

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/authority"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    auth="Container"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    maxActive="100"
    maxWait="10000"
    maxIdle="30"
    password="password"
    logAbandoned="true"
    username="username"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    url="jdbc:postgres://localhost:3306/realm"
/>
```

Realm configuration

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
   dataSourceName="jdbc/authority"
   userTable="users" 
   userNameCol="user_name" 
   userCredCol="user_pass"
   userRoleTable="user_roles" 
   roleNameCol="role_name"
/>
```

BTW you can check out the datasource realm here
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html

Comment: The strange thing is that happens with Tomcat-8, not with 6 or 7

Comment: Not sure why it may be somehting internally that has changed with the way tomcat is managing dbConnections. I looked through the tomcat source but the problem has to be that the dbConnection that is being passed to the credentials method is closed. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.8/org/apache/catalina/realm/JDBCRealm.java?av=f

Comment: Thanx for your detailed reply. 
It was long ago, but as far as I remember, JdbcReaml exception comes out after redeploing of application without restarting tomcat (i could be wrong). May be it's related with tomcat natural memory leaks?